# Parsing an array of objects in C#

Tags: c#, oop, parsing, data-structures, tibco

I have an array of objects and I would like to pass it into a method that only accepts `DOUBLE`, `NULL`, `STRING` or `DATETIME`. So when I try to pass in the value it gives an error saying I can't pass in any arbitrary object and that it has to be parsed as a `DOUBLE`, `NULL`, `STRING` or `DATETIME` first.

```
foreach (var currRow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var tuple = Com.Tibco.As.Space.Tuple.Create();

    //here is where i loop through the object array
    for (int i = 0; i < currRow.Values.Length; i++)
    {
        //here is where i try to pass it to the method (which doesn't accept it)
        tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], currRow.Values[i]);
    }

    inSpace_.Put(tuple);
}
```

[image: Heres what the array of objects look like]

In short I need a way to parse each object and cast it as the appropriate one and then put it inside the tuple.

**Edit**:

Here's what I tried to do, but it didn't work:

```
foreach (var currRow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var tuple = Com.Tibco.As.Space.Tuple.Create();

    for (int i = 0; i < currRow.Values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (currRow.Values[i] != null)
        {
            if (dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i].GetType().IsEquivalentTo(typeof(DateTime)))
            {
                DateTime value = DateTime.Parse(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i].ToString());
                tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], value);
            }
            else if (dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i].GetType().IsEquivalentTo(typeof(Double)))
            {
                Double value = Convert.ToDouble(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i]);
                tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], value);
            }
            else
            {
                string value = dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i].ToString();
                tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], value);
            }
        }
    }
    inSpace_.Put(tuple);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var currRow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var tuple = Com.Tibco.As.Space.Tuple.Create();

    for (int i = 0; i < currRow.Values.Length; i++)
    {
        var obj = dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], currRow.Values[i];
        var value = null;
        value = obj as double;
        if (!validObject(value)) value as string;
        if (!validObject(value)) value as DateTime;
        tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], value);
    }

    inSpace_.Put(tuple);
}

bool validObject(object obj) { return (null != obj); }
```

Update, based on your edit, I'd use a switch on type instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currRow.Values.Length; i++)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var obj = dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], currRow.Values[i];
    var value = null;
    switch (type)
    {
        case DateTime:
            value = DateTime.Parse(obj);
            break;
        case double:
            value = Convert.ToDouble(obj);
            break;
        case string:
            value = Convert.ToString(obj);
            break;
    }
    tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], value);
}
```

Comment: i think we're on the right track, but i don't just want to check and get what type it is. I want to parse each object differently depending on its own type. So if you getType() and it turns into datetime i will insert it like

 inSpace_.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], (DateTime)currRow.Values[i]);

Comment: Did you try version one? it will cast the obj based on the type it was able to cast as.

Comment: yeah ill try it, can you please look at the new code i posted when i tried to do it

Comment: @Ramie Updated with alternate version

Comment: @Ramie which one did you go with?

Comment: second one but changed it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type at compile-time, use `Convert.ToDouble`, `Convert.ToInt32`, etc. If you don't, use `Convert.ChangeType`.